# r - Error: 'variable name' not found in the data frame using slide() from DataCombine

Tags: r, apply

I am attempting to use the slide() function from DataCombine to create a lagged column for each variable in my dataframe, like so:

```
      Var1 Var2 ... VarN -->     Var1 Lag1 Var2 Lag2 ... VarN LagN.
2001   5     3  ...  1   --> 2001 5    2    3    8   ...  1    3
2002   2     8  ...  3   --> 2002 2    9    8    10  ...  3    4
2003   9     10 ...  4   --> 2003 9    --   10   --  ...  4    --
```

Here's what I've done so far:

```
mydata <- read.csv("myfile.csv", row.names = 1, stringAsFactors = FALSE)
mydata <- na.omit(mydata)
v <- as.vector(colnames(mydata))
laggeddata <- apply(mydata, 2, function(x) slide(x, Var = v, slideBy = -1))
```

Running this, I get: `"Error: Var1 not found in the data frame. Var2 was not found in the data frame..."` etc.

I'm fairly new to R, and I feel like there is some noob mistake I'm making.  Anyone willing to point out the error of my ways would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your approach is that `apply` applies the function slide for every column of `mydata`. Hence, for instance for the first column `slide(mydata[,1], Var = v, slideBy = -1)` is executed. However, the first column of `mydata` does not contain all the column names `v`. Therefore the error is raised.

Instead you could write your own function for laggig a single vector and then use `apply` to apply it on all columns:

```
mydata <- data.frame(A=1:4,B=4:1, C=6:9)

lag_by_minus_one <- function(x){c(x[-1],NA)}
df_lagged <- apply(mydata,2,lag_by_minus_one)
colnames(df_lagged) <- lapply(colnames(df_lagged), function(x){paste0(x,"_lag")})
```

**Edit:**
And then add the lagged version of the dataframe to the original data frame:

```
newdata<-cbind(mydata,df_lagged)

newdata
  A B C A_lag B_lag C_lag
1 1 4 6     2     3     7
2 2 3 7     3     2     8
3 3 2 8     4     1     9
4 4 1 9    NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: Thanks, otwtm, for your solution!  I am afraid the code as I've entered it in R outputs a value: 'df_lagged: Named logi [1:1525] NA NA NA NA ....'  What am I missing?

Comment: By lagging by one year, you lose one value in the beginning. The function lag_by_one fills this "gap" with NA. So if the output in your comment shows the first row of your data frame, it is expected.

Comment: I just realized that you lag in the other direction than I thought. I corrected my answer accordingly. The NA's are now produced in the end of the dataframe.

Comment: So right now my data frame is a matrix with a blank row added to the top of my columns.  I was hoping to create a new lagged column next to each variable,  replicating the data in the new column but offset by 1.  Have I missed something?

Comment: I added a mini example to my answer. Maybe this helps?

Comment: Brilliant.  This has been helpful.  IF I were to increase the lead or have it change direction, do I edit this part of the code `lag_by_minus_one <- function(x){c(x[-1],NA)}` to for example `function(x){c(x[6],NA)}` if I wanted a six period offset going in the other direction?

Comment: No. The lag-function in my answer lags only by one. But there are functions that are able to lag in both directions, and by several time steps. Looking at your own answer, you seem to have found the function "lead".

Answer (score 0):

Worked out an answer aided by the otwtm's response:

```
laggeddata <- apply(mydata, 2 function(x) lead(x, n = 1))
colnames(laggeddata) <- lapply, colnames(laggeddata), funciton(x){paste(x,"- lag)})
newdata <- cbind(laggeddata, mydata)
```

For anyone looking to tweak this, you can change n to change the lead interval or change lead to lag if you want the new column to be offset after your data.